# Arrow between two graphics

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-arrows

I have two charts and I would like to place an arrow as shown in the figure:

[image]

I am using pgfplots for the graphics, in fact this is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usepackage[margin = 0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}


\resizebox{0.4\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid,
        grid style = {dashed},
        axis lines = left,
        xlabel = \(t\),
        ylabel = {\(f(t)\)},
        ]
        %Below the red parabola is defined
        \addplot [
        domain=0:pi, 
        samples=1200, 
        color=black,
        line width=1pt,
        ]
        {sin(deg(x))};
        
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\resizebox{0.4\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid,
        grid style = {dashed},
        axis lines = left,
        xlabel = \(t\),
        ylabel = {\(g(t)\)},
        ]
        %Below the red parabola is defined
        \addplot [
        domain=0:pi, 
        samples=100, 
        color=black,
        line width=1pt,
        ]
        {sin(deg(x/2))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put both plots in the same `tikzpicture` and use a `scope` environment for the second one to shift it globally. Then you can use a simple `\draw` to add an arrow between them.

Also, avoid `\resizebox`, it usually gives bad results. Use the `scale` option for `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usepackage[margin = 0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
    \begin{axis}[
        grid,
        grid style = {dashed},
        axis lines = left,
        xlabel = \(t\),
        ylabel = {\(f(t)\)},
        ]
        %Below the red parabola is defined
        \addplot [
        domain=0:pi, 
        samples=1200, 
        color=black,
        line width=1pt,
        ]
        {sin(deg(x))};
        
    \end{axis}

    \draw[ultra thick, ->, >=latex] (7.3,3)--++(1,0);

    \begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
    \begin{axis}[
        grid,
        grid style = {dashed},
        axis lines = left,
        xlabel = \(t\),
        ylabel = {\(g(t)\)},
        ]
        %Below the red parabola is defined
        \addplot [
        domain=0:pi, 
        samples=100, 
        color=black,
        line width=1pt,
        ]
        {sin(deg(x/2))};
    \end{axis}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

A small variation of @Miyase answer:

- plots are named,
- arrows coordinates are determined by plots names
- axis styles are collected in common `\pgfplotsset`
- `xtick7s and their label are in ˙pi` units

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 0.9in]{geometry}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\pgfplotsset{
    width=0.4\linewidth,
        axis lines = left,
        grid,
        grid style = {dashed},
        xlabel = \(t\),
        xtick = {0,pi/3,2*pi/3,pi},
        xticklabels = {0,$\pi/3$, $2\pi/3$, $\pi$},
        domain = 0:pi,
        samples = 101,
        no marks,
every axis plot post/.append style={thick,red},
        trig format plots=rad,
            }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel = {\(f(t)\)}, name=plot1]
        %Below the red parabola is defined
\addplot {sin(x)};
\end{axis}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
\begin{axis}[ylabel = {\(g(t)\)}, name=plot2]
\addplot {sin(x/2)};
\end{axis}
    \end{scope}
    
\draw[ultra thick, -Latex, shorten <=7mm, shorten >=17mm] (plot1) -- (plot2);

\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]